Error while installing "Kate-plugins" via pipx
I was intending to install a "kate-plugins" via pipx on Arch linux btw, but jokes aside I get this error
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    /home/tahayasseradnan/.local/state/pipx/log/cmd_2024-06-12_23.10.20_pip_errors.log

pip seemed to fail to build package:
    pysmell==0.7.3

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?

Error installing kate-plugins.

For anyone asking for the log here it is:
PIP STDOUT
----------
Collecting kate-plugins
  Using cached Kate-plugins-0.2.3.tar.gz (211 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting pysmell==0.7.3 (from kate-plugins)
  Using cached pysmell-0.7.3.zip (48 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

PIP STDERR
----------
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/tahayasseradnan/.local/share/pipx/shared/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/tahayasseradnan/.local/share/pipx/shared/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/tahayasseradnan/.local/share/pipx/shared/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p0emiyie/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p0emiyie/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p0emiyie/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p0emiyie/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 27
          print post_install_message
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip

I did some researchers and tried the old  solutions I found,nothing solved my problem,any help would be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print' This error means you're trying to run code that was written for Python 2.

https://pypi.org/project/Kate-plugins/ last version 0.2.3 was released in 2013. Requires Python 2.6, not even 2.7. Though you can try it with Python 2.7 but certainly not with 3+.

so i guess I should find another one for python3

@taha_28 https://github.com/goinnn/Kate-plugins#information
